# Is there a way to set focus to parent tab on opening a child tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

> The following code sets focus on the new tab, not to the opener.

```js
function openChildtab() {
  var win = window.open("https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B01J90O0N4/ref=sv_kinc_2", "_blank");
  if (win) {
    window.focus();
  } else {
    alert("Please allow popups for this website");
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick="openChildtab()">Open New tab</a>
```

Comment: The term for this is ["popunder"](/search?q=popunder)/["pop-under"](/search?q=pop-under). You should be able to find an answer with that term (here, or on the web generally).

Comment: Thanks. I will search using the terms

Comment: don't know from parent window but from child window after opening new window you can call `window.parent.focus()` on body `onload`

Comment: Thanks for your response.The openChildtab() function used in many pages. some parent windows need focus and some don't. It would be better if I can control it from the opener window.